# Loop index in included nunjucks file

Tags: loops, nunjucks

So I came across a peculiar thing in nunjucks that I really need a fix for.

Imagine I have a loop in i.e. **index.nj**

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% include "/file2.nj" %}
{% endfor %}
```

now in **file2.nj** I wish to address the loop index as follows:

```
{{ loop.index }}
```

This doesn't work for some reason but the weird part is that if I first add a call to **loop.index** in the **index.nj** file, it does.

i.e.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{loop.index}}
    {% include "/file2.nj" %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the example above, **file2.nj** can call **loop.index** itself.
Why does it not know loop.index first but when I call it upfront (this can also be in an **if** that does nothing, I tested), the file does have access to it?

I would be overjoyed if anyone knows how to fix this.

Comment: maybe you could use a macro and pass in loop.index to be able to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, resolved in this pull request: https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/pull/280

If you want an upstream that fixes this, change your `package.json` to use: `"nunjucks": "git://github.com/amyboyd/nunjucks.git"`